# switching test to production > main menu forgotten, background forgotten

Tags: menus, migration

the bigger question is:
How to have a beta (test) site and production, and switch between them so easily that a user can do it.

I **wrote a script** that does the move. Here's what the script does:

```
1. saves the target wp-config DB settings
2. dumps source_DB, with --add-drop-table --add-drop-database 
3. replaces all http://source/ with http://target in dump_DB.sql
4. loads source_DB.sql in Target_DB
5. (there is no cache plugin in either sites)
6. rsync --delete /source/path/ to /target/path
7. chown -R /target/path  with the correct ownership
```

The script works perfectly. the source-site is practically identical to the target-site. The files are md5-identical between the srouce and target (except wp-config.php).

BUT!  (here's are questions)

- The main menu is "forgotten".  I have to manually go to "menus" and select the main-menu from the drop-down box.   it happens each time i switch these websites. **How can that be, if the database is copied 1:1  ?**  Could it be that the menu is related to domain URL somehow?
- the background **preference** (controlled by "simplify" theme") is forgotten. I have to manually select the background images from existing images.
- Is there a better way to switch test-site <> production site without all this hassle?  I Just want to have a test site and to switch DNS entries. My posts dont travel over the internet, so I dont need absolute URLS.  changing "hosts" file solution is not acceptable for admin end-user.

Answer (score 1):

There's a set of tutorials on how to deploy WordPress (source and DB) using Capistrano.

[Part 1](http://theme.fm/2011/08/tutorial-deploying-wordpress-with-capistrano-2082/)
 | [Part 2](http://theme.fm/2011/09/deploying-wordpress-with-capistrano-part-2-staging-servers-tagging-database-security-2213/)
 | [Part 3](http://theme.fm/2011/11/deploying-wordpress-with-capistrano-part-3-backing-up-and-restoring-mysql-2922/)

Capistrano allows you to deploy WordPress installations from the command line.  It was initially developed for Ruby on Rails apps, but it has the capability to deploy many other systems, apparently.

There's information in the tutorials on:

- setting up Capistrano
- "capifying" WordPress
- deploying to multiple servers
  (so you can, for instance, have test/staging/production
  environments)
- using Capistrano to manage your WP databases (including backup & restore)

I haven't had a chance to try it yet, but I'm really itching to.

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [FAQ#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Comment: Updated my answer.  If it's still insufficient, let me know and I'll edit further or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just do a plain text string replacement on database dump - that breaks any serialized data, that contains string being replaced, and WordPress uses that plenty.

Only use replacement tools with support of serialized data, such as [Search-Replace-DB](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB).